# Magento 2 modify contact us page

Tags: magento, magento2.1

can somebody explain how i can modify the contact us page. I would like to insert a custom block with google maps inside that covers the full width of the page. The rest of the page will stay with the same layout (space on ether side of the content).

[image]

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking about the usual statics block, which can be added through the admin panel, then so:

1) create a static block with your content

> Content > Block

2) create a widget and bring to the right place the static block

> Content > Widgets

with such parameters as on the screen 
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've followed your steps but the widget is not visible on the contact page. If i change the widget settings to show the widget on the homepage then it is visible. Do you know why?

Comment: And if you switch the skin to a Luma, is it displayed?

Comment: I look likes if i change the skin the skin on the contact page isn't changing. Does the contact page have this own settings?

Comment: If you have a standard page and a form, then you can find a layout here
vendor\magento\module-contact\view\frontend\layout\

If the page is standard, and  you change the skin and everything looks correct, the widget should be displayed.

Comment: I've removed the module -contact\view\frontend\layout\contact_index_index.xml but nothing happens, so i think there must by another file. (i also cleared the cache) Im using the destino theme

Comment: This file contains the name of a unique page on which to display the widget.